# Create Docker image that copies folder from directory when used as FROM in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to create a Docker image that can be used in other Dockerfiles to build these projects. Therefore I need to copy the files from the context of the specific project into the container that is built.

Is it possible with docker to create an image that can be used in other Dockerfiles and that executes the commands specified in the Dockerfile of the image when building the project-specific Dockerfile? Or are there any other solutions for this? Like "template" images or Dockerfiles.

What I want to achieve is an image I can simply specify in my projects Dockerfile and it builds the current project. When I update the image of every project should be updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [**multi-stage builds**](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) and has a whole page dedicated to it in the documentation as you might see.

You can typically use it to build dependencies in the upper stage that you will be able to use later.

Here is one of the examples of the documentation:

> ```
> FROM golang:1.7.3 AS builder 
> WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/ 
> RUN go get -d -v golang.org/x/net/html   
> COPY app.go    . 
> RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o app .
>
> FROM alpine:latest   
> RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates 
> WORKDIR /root/ 
> COPY --from=builder /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/app . 
> CMD ["./app"]
> ```

<sup>*Source: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#name-your-build-stages*</sup>

And further in the documentation:

> [**Use an external image as a “stage”**](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-an-external-image-as-a-stage)
>
> When using multi-stage builds, you are not limited to copying from
>   stages you created earlier in your Dockerfile. You can use the `COPY --from` instruction to copy from a separate image, either using the local image name, a tag available locally or on a Docker registry, or
>   a tag ID. The Docker client pulls the image if necessary and copies
>   the artifact from there. The syntax is:
>
> ```
> COPY --from=nginx:latest /etc/nginx/nginx.conf /nginx.conf
> ```

So you can definitly have your own image, out of a *Dockerfile*, build it with:

```
docker build . -t my-namespace/template
```

Then in your "application" *Dockerfile* copy back the files you need:

```
FROM alpine
COPY --from=my-namespace/template:latest /path/from/template /path/in/app
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. I'm already using multistage builds. I tried out your suggestion but I think it's not working. What I need to copy are the source files that need to be inside the container before other commands are executed (build). Is this also possible?

Comment: Sure, in the _Dockerfile_ of `my-namespace/template` copy your files from your host to this image, then `COPY --from` it from that template image to your "app" image.